# Getting qgis-ltr-bin.exe - System Error?

Tags: qgis, error

I have installed QGIS 2.8 but when I double click on QGIS desktop it shows an error

> qgis-ltr-bin.exe - System Error
>
> The program can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is
>   missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this
>   problem.

Comment: This is rather outdated version (QGIS 2.8). Where do you get it? Try installer from [qgis.org](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html) or [nextgis.com](http://nextgis.com/nextgis-qgis/)

Comment: Related and off-topic here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33265663/api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll-is-missing-when-opening-microsoft-office-file

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact same error message in another program in Windows OS, and I had resolved it by installing **Universal C Runtime driver**. I don't have that problem happening at my end (and I'm working on Ubuntu OS) so I can't test this out, but give it a shot and let us know if it helped:

Excerpt:

> This program requires a small driver called "Universal C Runtime". It
>   is usually covered in Windows Update and is already present in win10,
>   but in case your system doesn't have it, please install it from here:
>   https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows
>   and then run the program. You may need to restart your system for the
>   driver to be fully installed.
>
> Without this, on running the exe you may get a popup error sayng:
>   "Entry point not found: The procedure entry point ucrtbase.abort could
>   not be located in the dynamic link library
>   api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll"

Full post with other details not related: https://github.com/WRI-Cities/static-GTFS-manager/issues/63#issuecomment-427424257